# Create a Angular 2 mobile app

Tags: android, ionic-framework, angular

I have made a website using **Angular 2**. I would like to create a mobile app out of this website. I am hoping this will make the site run faster on smartphones. I thought that if I transferred my Angular 2 site into a mobile app most files would not have to be downloaded every time the page is visited.

Is this a good idea? Will it speed the app up? Does anyone have other suggestions?

PS: I have used Ionic but I don’t want to rewrite the app using the ionic framework, instead I would like to use the existing code to build a mobile app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should look into **Apache Cordova**. This is what **ionic** uses to access the native functionality of the device. [here is a link for the site](https://cordova.apache.org/) You can use any form of js, css, or html. it also has plugins you can use. Go though the Get Started button and then start the tutorial should help you out.

With Cordova you start with a blank slate and can build an app using whatever JavaScript libraries or frameworks you want. *So it will **support Angular 2***.

Speed will depend on how many ajax calls you make and the logic you use to create the app functionality. Having the website stored on device will speed up the initial load of the js, css, and html. But if you have good internet speed and not much to load the speed up will not be noticeable.

I think the real advantage of having a native app (even through Cordova) is that you will have native access to the device file system and functionality that you would not have with a website. Check out the [plugins](https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/) for Cordova. Push notification, camera or any number of other [plugins](https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/)...

Comment: Cordova libraries are frequently deprecated.